# Export Console.Beep() Series to File

Tags: .net, audio, export

I'm working on a side project for [HAM Radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_radio) examination where the user enters text and [Morse Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) is played back utilizing .NET's `Console.Beep()`.

I'm looking for possible solutions to export this as a recording (audio file) for later playback using standard audio players (Media Player, etc.). Any recommendations on existing code or free/open source libraries? Thanks.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not export it as a MIDI file using a library like [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: After a quick review of the site, it looks promising. Thanks for the link!